# C# EF Core WHERE IN LINQ from List with .Contains return nothing

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

```
var ids = new List<string>();

foreach (int rowHandle in this.viewRateManager.GetSelectedRows())
{
    ids.Add(this.viewRateManager.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, "Id").ToString());
}

var spr = this.contextSQL.ProductSubProductRate
                   .Where(e => e.Id.Contains(ids.ToString()));

DateTime time = this.contextSQL.Database
                   .SqlQuery<DateTime>($"SELECT NOW()")
                   .AsEnumerable()
                   .FirstOrDefault();

foreach (var item in spr)
{
    if (item.Approver != null) { continue; }

    item.Approver = Core.cxCore.ActiveAccount;
    item.Approved = time;
}

this.contextSQL.SaveChanges();
```

Yesterday I spent the night to finally able to multi-approve the data, and simplify some code. It was a very good sleep.
This morning I continued my work, it does not work anymore. Though I moved to another PC via cloud, but should be the same. I am still searching for why it didn't work and why yesterday it works like charm. I want to confirm if I can do it like this?

```
.Where(e => e.Id.Contains(ids.ToString()));
```

Because when I removed .Where, it works. So there must be something wrong with the .Contains.
I checked ids and it returns exact string identifier correctly.

Comment: Your `Contains` is the wrong way around, currently you're checking if the ID on the database contains `ids.ToString()`, instead you should check the other way around , i.e change your `Where` to `Where(e => ids.Contains(e.Id))`.

Comment: It works! But I really don't get it. Usually you would do select, where specific columns contains something you need. Like where-in case, which whatever inside the in bracket should be definitely the things inside my List, not the way around.

Comment: Yes, when you search for one value to be equal or part of your ```Id```, But when you have a list of values, ```Linq``` looks backwards to be able to assemble a correct query with full list of values. You just have to learn and remember that syntax.

Comment: While `List<T>.ToString()` does return a string, that's probably not very useful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote the logic with the `Contains` backwards

```
var spr = this.contextSQL.ProductSubProductRate.Where(e => e.Id.Contains(ids.ToString()));
```

Replace with

```
var spr = this.contextSQL.ProductSubProductRate.Where(e => ids.Contains(е.Id));
```

Comment: shouldn't `x.Id` be `e.Id`? Can't edit because of a minimum of 6 character edit limitation

Comment: True, transcription error